# read data from requestHeader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my application I am doing Ajax request to the server

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader(ZO_KEY1, _key1);
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader(ZO_KEY2, _key2);
            },
            url: "http://192.168.1.4:3000/api/getNotes",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  alert("aaaaa"+data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert("bbbbb" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

How could I get the value from RequestHeader using Ruby on Rails

```
def get_notes

    @notes = Note.find:all
    render :json => @notes

  end
```

I want get key1 and key2 from setRequestHeader. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, it has. You can access the request header `request.headers['ZO_KEY1']`.

Check this for more detail, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

Comment: Sorry bro I did this but I have nil result

Comment: Turn on firebug, and check the request headers on the ajax request has been sent or not.